# list index out of range but it seems impossible since it's only after 3 questions

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
kanji = ['上','下','大','工','八','入','山','口','九','一','人','力','川','七','十','三','二','女',]
reading = ['じょう','か','たい','こう','はち','にゅう','さん','こう','く','いち','にん','りょく','かわ','しち','じゅう','さん','に','じょ']
definition = ['above','below','big','construction','eight','enter','mountain','mouth','nine','one','person','power','river','seven','ten','three','two','woman']

score = number_of_questions = kanji_item = 0

def question_format(prompt_type,lang,solution_selection):
    global reading,definition,score,num_of_questions,kanji_item
    question_prompt = 'What is the '+str(prompt_type)+' for "'+str(kanji[kanji_item])+'"? (Keyboard:'+str(lang)+')\n'
    solution_selection = [reading,definition]
    usr = input(question_prompt)
    if usr in solution_selection[kanji_item] and kanji[kanji_item]:
        score += 1
        num_of_questions += 1
    else:
        pass
    kanji_item += 1

while number_of_questions != 18:
    question_format('READING','Japanese',[0])
print('You got ',score,'/',number_of_questions)

while number_of_questions != 36:
    question_format('DEFINITION','English',[1])
print('You got ',score,'/',number_of_questions)
```

I can't get past 大. but I can't see where it's messing up. I've tried to change pretty much everything. "kanji_item" is supposed to give a common index number so that the answers can match up. It gets through the first two problems with no hassle, but for some reason refuses to accept my third problem.

Comment: You're testing `number_of_questions` but in your function you update `num_of_questions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:
- wrong name using `number_of_questions` vs. `num_of_questions`
- wrong way to check truthyness `if usr in solution_selection[kanji_item] and kanji[kanji_item]:` - the last part is always `True` as it is a non empty string 
- lots of globals wich is not considered very good style

It would be easier to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) your three list together so you get tuples of (kanji, reading, description)  and feed 2 of those into your function depending on what you want to test. You do this 2 times, once for reading, once for description.

You can even randomize your list of tuples to get different "orders" in which questions are asked:

```
kanji = ['上', '下', '大', '工', '八', '入', '山', '口', '九', '一' , '人', 
         '力', '川', '七', '十', '三', '二', '女',]
reading = ['じょう', 'か', 'たい', 'こう', 'はち', 'にゅう', 'さん', 'こう', 'く',
           'いち', 'にん', 'りょく', 'かわ', 'しち', 'じゅう', 'さん', 'に', 'じょ']
definition = ['above', 'below', 'big', 'construction', 'eight', 'enter', 'mountain', 
              'mouth', 'nine', 'one', 'person', 'power', 'river', 'seven', 'ten', 'three', 
              'two', 'woman']

import random

data = list(zip(kanji, reading, definition))
random.shuffle(data)

def question_format(prompt_type, lang, kanji, solution):
    """Creates a question about *kanji* - the correct answer is *solution*
    Returns 1 if correct else 0."""
    question_prompt = f'What is the {prompt_type} for {kanji}? (Keyboard: {lang})'
    usr = input(question_prompt)
    if usr == solution:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

questions_asked = 0
correct = 0
for (kanji, reading, _) in data:
    correct += question_format('READING','Japanese', kanji, reading)
    questions_asked += 1

print('You got ',correct,'/',questions_asked)

for (kanji, _, definition) in data: 
    correct += question_format('DEFINITION','ENGLISH', kanji, definition)
    questions_asked += 1

print('You got ',correct,'/',questions_asked)
```

After [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ping our list and shuffling them `data` looks like

```
[('山', 'さん', 'mountain'), ('女', 'じょ', 'woman'), ('力', 'りょく', 'power'), 
('上', 'じょう', 'above'), ('九', 'く', 'nine'), ('川', 'かわ', 'river'), 
('入', 'にゅう', 'enter'), ('三', 'さん', 'three'), ('口', 'こう', 'mouth'), 
('二', 'に', 'two'), ('人', 'にん', 'person'), ('七', 'しち', 'seven'), 
('一', 'いち', 'one'), ('工', 'こう', 'construction'), ('下', 'か', 'below'), 
('八', 'はち', 'eight'), ('十', 'じゅう', 'ten'), ('大', 'たい', 'big')]
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I'm still super new to programming, so thanks for the styling tips and new ways to think about how to solve this problem. :D